# Equivalent of list.index() for an OrderedDict?

Tags: python, dictionary, ordereddictionary

Given that by its very nature, the items in an [`OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) are ordered, one might expect it to have a function similar to the `index` function of lists. It does not.

What is the most Pythonic / neatest way of mimicing `index` for an `OrderedDict`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27726326/742269

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends what you want the `index` of.
If you want the index of a key, you can just do

```
o = OrderedDict([('toast',5.80),('waffles',2.30),('pancakes',3.99)])
print o.keys().index('waffles')
```

Comment: Precisely what I needed.